# Automatically update people's ages in sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite, date

How do I automatically update people's age in an SQLite database? I have put their `DateOfBirth` column, and I created another column called `Today` which is supposed to display the current date by putting 
`Set Today = date('now')` function.
Then I made created the `Age` column which calculates their age by subtracting their birth dates from the current date (Today-Date of birth), which seems to do the job.
But, the problem is that the TODAY isn't automatically updated, what do I do? Thanks everyone in advance, cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I automatically update people's age in an SQLite database?

You don't need to since `Age` is a computed column and thus while displaying the data you can calculate the age and show it accordingly. Since you already have DOB stored you just need to get teh difference from `CurrentDay - DOB` to get the age.

Use a `UPDATE` statement to update your `Today` column

```
update your_table set Today = date('now')
```

Comment: Thanks Rahul, but I need this Age column to be always displayed in the table view.

Comment: @AleksandarIlijevski, in that case create a `view` rather than adding an extra column to your table

Comment: yes, I removed the 'Age' and 'Today' columns, and created a view with the computed Age and current date. So this view will update itself daily? If yes, thank you so much :)

Comment: @AleksandarIlijevski, Yes, since it's a view, when you run it it's actualy going to execute the underlying SQL which will going to get you the current date and data thus. Also, consider accepting the answer by clicking the check mark if it helped.

Comment: Hey, and when I get Ages to be equal to *2016*, how do I change the code so that It doesn't show that as a result, but still displays those people with empty Age fields?